# Zend findParentRow: Unrecognized method

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm a newbie in developpment and in Zend Framework. And I'm going crazy with this problem, I don't know why it doesn't work.

My app is a mobile phones managment.
I have 2 classes: 'Fabriquant' and 'Modele'. So, for example, I have a mobile device with Fabriquant: Apple, and Modele: iPhone 4S.

I would like to display the list of all mobile devices recorded in my DB. I have to find the 'Fabriquant' data for each 'Modele' in my view.

Here is my code:

```
    index.phtml
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Fabriquant</th>
    <th>Modèle</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    foreach($this->modele as $modele) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($modele->getFabriquant()->FAB_NOM); // $modele->FAB_ID affiche bien l'ID du fabriquant></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($modele->MOD_NOM);?></td>
    <td>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'modele',
    'action'=>'modifier', 'id'=>$modele->MOD_ID));?>">Modifier</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'modele',
    'action'=>'supprimer', 'id'=>$modele->MOD_ID));?>">Supprimer</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

So this line have a problem:

> escape($modele->getFabriquant()->FAB_NOM);

My Fabriquant.php:
class Application_Model_DbTable_Fabriquant extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

```
protected $_name    = 'fabriquant';
protected $_primary = 'FAB_ID';     // La primary key
protected $_fabNom  = 'FAB_NOM';
```

Here is my Modele.php:
class Application_Model_DbTable_Modele extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

```
protected $_name        = 'modele';     // Le nom de la table dans la BDD
protected $_primary     = 'MOD_ID';     // La clef primaire dans la table de la BDD
protected $_fabId       = 'FAB_ID';
protected $_modNom      = 'MOD_NOM';
protected $_rowClass    = 'ModeleRow';  //Le nom de la classe Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract

protected $_referenceMap = array(   // La table fabriquant dépendante
    'fabriquant' => array(
                    'columns'       =>  'FAB_ID',       // Colonne de la clé primaire
                    'refTableClass' =>  'Fabriquant',   // Nom de la CLASSE correspondante
                    'refColumns'    =>  'FAB_ID'
    )
);
```

...

This is my ModeleRow.php:
class ModeleRow extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {

```
public function getFabriquant(){
    $fabriquant = $this->findParentRow('fabriquant');
}
```

}

I have this error message, and the following stack:

```
Message: Unrecognized method 'getFabriquant()' 

Stack trace:

#0 D:\PHP Workspace\mona\application\views\scripts\modele\index.phtml(21): Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->__call('getFabriquant', Array)
#1 D:\PHP Workspace\mona\application\views\scripts\modele\index.phtml(21): Zend_Db_Table_Row->getFabriquant()
#2 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\View.php(108): include('D:\PHP Workspac...')
#3 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(888): Zend_View->_run('D:/PHP Workspac...')
#4 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(900): Zend_View_Abstract->render('modele/index.ph...')
#5 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(921): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('modele/index.ph...', NULL)
#6 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(960): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#7 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#8 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(527): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#9 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#10 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#11 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#12 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#13 D:\PHP Workspace\mona\public\index.php(98): Zend_Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

I guess this would be a newbie question, but I'm on it for 2 days, and I don't find the problem... Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT:
Here is my ModeleController.php (sorry, there are all my personal comments...)

class ModeleController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

```
public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    Zend_Loader::loadClass("Modele", APPLICATION_PATH . "/models"); // indique l'emplacement du modèle
    //require_once 'FabriquantController.php';
    $this->view->title = "Liste des modèles"; // le titre affiché
    // Traitement du controleur
    $modele = new Modele();
    //.....traitement...

    // Transmet à la vue
    $this->view->modele = $modele->fetchAll();
        }

public function ajouterAction()
{
    $this->view->title = "Ajouter un nouveau modèle";
    $form = new Application_Form_Modele();                  // Création du formulaire
    //var_dump($form);
    $form->envoyer->setLabel('Ajouter');                        // Ajout d'un libellé au bouton d'envoi
    $this->view->form = $form;      

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $fabAccessData  = new Application_Model_DbTable_Fabriquant();
            $idFab          = $form->getValue('FAB_NOM');
            $nomModele      = $form->getValue('MOD_NOM');
            $accessData     = new Application_Model_DbTable_Modele();

            $accessData->ajouterModele($idFab, $nomModele);

            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}

public function lireAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function supprimerAction()
{
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');
        if ($del == 'Oui') {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
            $modele = new Application_Model_DbTable_Modele();
            $modele->supprimerModele($id);
        }
        $this->_helper->redirector('index');
    } else {
        $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
        $modele = new Application_Model_DbTable_Modele();
        $this->view->modele = $modele->getModele($id);
    }
}

public function modifierAction()
{
$this->view->title = "Modifier un modèle";
    $form = new Application_Form_Modele();                  // Création du formulaire
    $form->setAction($this->view->url(array('controller' => 'modele', 'action' => 'modifier'), 'default', true));
    $form->envoyer->setLabel('Modifier');                       // Ajout d'un libellé au bouton d'envoi
    $this->view->form = $form;                                  // Envoi du formulaire à la vue

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {                        // si la méthode isPost de l'objet Request renvoi True, le formulaire à été envoyé
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();             // Récupération des données avec la méthode getPost()
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                        // Vérification de ces données avec la méthode isValid()


            $id = (int)$form->getValue('MOD_ID');               // Récupération de l'ID du fabriquant
            $nomFabriquant = $form->getValue('FAB_NOM');
            $fabriquant = new Application_Model_DbTable_Fabriquant();
            $idFabriquant = $fabriquant->getIdFabricant($nomFabriquant);
            $nomModele = $form->getValue('MOD_NOM');            // On récupère le nom du fabriquant
            $modele = new Application_Model_DbTable_Modele();   // On créé un nouvel enregistrement
            $modele->modifierModele($id, $idFabriquant, $nomModele);    // On affecte à cet enregistrement le nom du fabriquant, et on persiste en BDD
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');                // pour finir, on redirige vers index de Fabriquant
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);                         // Si la validation n'est pas passée, on réaffiche les données dans le formulaire
        }
    }
    else {
            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            //var_dump($id);
            if ($id > 0) {

                $modele = new Application_Model_DbTable_Modele();
                $fabriquant = new Application_Model_DbTable_Fabriquant();
                $Fabriquant = $fabriquant->getFabriquant($id);
                $nomFabriquant = $Fabriquant['FAB_NOM'];
                //var_dump($nomFabriquant);
                $nomModele = $modele->getModele($id);
                echo "L'ID du modèle est : " . $id;     // Vérification
                //echo "L'ID du fabriquant est : " . $nomFabriquant['FAB_NOM'];     // Vérification
                $form->populate($nomModele, $nomFabriquant);
                //$form->populate($nomFabriquant);
            } else {
                echo "Information : nous sommes dans le else de modifierAction de FabriquantController.php";
                echo "L'ID est : " . $id;
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Please can you post the code where you fetch the model? i.e. `$table = new MyTable(); $row = $table->fetchRow($table->where('id=?',1));`

Answer (score 0):

salut ,

in the Frabicant class you may need to say what are the dependent tables i think.

```
 protected $_dependentTables = array('Application_Model_DbTable_Modele');
```

in the model class , the ref map is wrong i think :

```
protected $_referenceMap = array(   // La table fabriquant dépendante
    'fabriquant' => array(
                    'columns'       =>  array('FAB_ID'),    
                    'refTableClass' =>  'Application_Model_DbTable_Fabriquant',  
    )
);
```

and columns should be an array.

ps : i suggest you name your tables in your RDBMS in the plural form but name your models in the singular form. And when you have the time you can check Zend/Doctrine integration.

**EDIT**

i'm pretty sure this line is wrong :

protected $_rowClass    = 'ModeleRow';

you have to write the entire name of the class , not just the name of the file.

Comment: These changes didn't solved the problem, the getFabriquant() method is still not recognized... For the plural form for the tables, my MERISE teacher told us to write them in the singular one... That's why... But I guess it allows to make the difference, right?

Comment: i know MERISE , but when you'll have to find a work you'll use Entity/Relation or UML to model your database.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Camus. I wrote this like that because I adapted this from this tutorial: http://www.reseaucerta.org/cotecours/ccMVC/index.html#id2747208. And in this tutorial, we have this: <?php
class City extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {    
  protected $_name = 'City';
  protected $_primary = 'id';
  protected $_rowClass = 'CityRow';